# How to add composite object to the hashtable's value?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I want to add an object (that contains many fields ) to a hashtable in order to access it again ...How is the right way to do this ? 
This is what it was doing ..
The object's class's name is LetterInfo.

```
hashtable.Add(e.KeyValue,new LetterInfo () );
```

However `hashtable[key].` 
Isn't working

I want to have a hashtable of objects (same of having array of objects )

Comment: 1) Don't use `HashTable` unless you're programming in C# 1.0.  Use `Dictionary`.  2) What's the type of your key?

Comment: @Servy key's  type is (char)KeyEventArgs e.KeyValue

Comment: If you're using a `char` as the key then you're not passing in the key of an existing pair in the table.

Comment: @Servy And by using dictionary i could add a multi filed object to it ?

Comment: Using a dictionary won't change the potential for what can be added in the general case, it just makes sure that all of the keys/values have a common type that you get to define, and ensures that the objects come out of the collection as that type.  This avoids issues with you accidentally adding objects of the wrong type, and avoids the need to cast objects you pull out of it.

Comment: A `Dictionary` can contain any kind of object. You should probably specify a particular class type for the entry values, though.